# Getting Nth Element using Xpath and Jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, xpath, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to traverse through an XML file using jquery mobile.

My code goes as below

```
testsss = $(xmlHttpRequest).find("Table OrganizationName:first").text();
```

Now I can get the first OrganisationID element by using the code (`"Table OrganizationName:first"`) but wot if I want to get the 3rd element?? is there any way to do it in Jquery??

Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery:eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) is what you are looking for.

```
$(xmlHttpRequest).find("Table OrganizationName:eq(2)").text();
```

Otherwise try to read the data with PHP [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

Comment: it doesn't work when I try '$(xmlHttpRequest).find("Table OrganizationName:nth-child(1)").text();'

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/ worked for me. update your answer so I can mark it as correct answer